# IF AND works incorrectly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am building IF(AND formula in Excel with 3 conditions. The formula is looking as follows: IF(AND(I2="#N/A N/A",J2<>"#N/A Field Not Applicable",K2<>"#N/A N/A"),"A",IF(AND(J2="#N/A Field Not Applicable",K2="#N/A N/A"),"B","Ok")).

Problem: for some reason, I don't get anything returned for first condition: IF(AND(I2="#N/A N/A",J2<>"#N/A Field Not Applicable",K2<>"#N/A N/A"),"A". The remaining part of the formula works fine and delivers correct output.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to make this formula work correctly, so it returns "A" in some cases.

Comment: What is the goal? I think you want to use the function ISNA() rather than testing against strings "#N/A".

Answer (score 0):

The If formula does not work to see if there was a mistake in a cell. The Excel tries to get a value from your cell, gets a mistake, and then you receive the error. Are you trying to concatenate differents "#N/A" in the formulas, for example for comparing "I2 = #N/A N/A"? This alone can result in the same problem I mentioned, when you try to concatenate a cell with a mistake.
As someone suggested, use the formula ISNA(I2) instead, which sees if the cell has a #N/A mistake and returns True or False. You can even do this in the concatenate, for example:

```
   =CONCAT(IF(ISNA(A2),"No Match", "Has a Match"), IF(ISNA(B2),"No Match", "Has a Match") )
```

That way, you can later compare I2, J2 and so on with other texts, not "#N/A", which isn't technically a text, and avoid this problem.